# bitcoin transaction spent but not received

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, blockchain.info, transaction-verification

I hope you are well.
I had a weird transaction which was sent a few days ago,
it now says spent, and received but has not changed my wallet balance, sent it from one exchange to another. When it is spent, does it still have to be credited to your wallet somehow?
https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/bddc545bb6963e964d82f6c80b1b8915f6cc94e228ea848818905fbc396a2a88/

Thanks,
Deon

Comment: yes, very much somehow, it would have to be credited. But: the tx number is currently not visible, so there is no possibility to see, what happened. I guess it might be somewhere "hanging", but other block explorers don't show it. When you say, it is spent, who rovides this info? And who provided the tx number?

Comment: @pebwindkraft thanks for the response! Oh, sorry, so if you look at blockchain.info or any blockchain for that matter, you will see it says spent, for one of the two amounts sent, for transaction, bddc545bb6963e964d82f6c80b1b8915f6cc94e228ea848818905fbc396a2a88

Comment: oh, so the transaction number was provided by the sending exchange, for some reason there are two amounts, mine and someone else's' maybe?

Comment: Ah, now I see it on blockchain.info. Yes. And ii has 57 confirmations right now. So if your providers wallet (exchange?) is linked to this address ("19wRqfMcdp2v1CuRGfJDdRKku4JMh5fUhX"), you should see the funds. The second amount is usually a return address for the change. Like if you pay for 45 Euros with a 50 euro bill, and get 5 back ...

Comment: @pebwindkraft, thanks I see, but my final balance has not changed, it says received x in total, but nothing in the final balance so it means what exactly?
https://blockchain.info/address/17eQCDAkfhSSB71kYis9UL4KioXdrgk5q1

Comment: 19wRqfMcdp2v1CuRGfJDdRKku4JMh5fUhX, is their address where the refund when to probably, and this is my one, 17eQCDAkfhSSB71kYis9UL4KioXdrgk5q1

Comment: I can see that the 17eQCDA... address spent 50 bitcoins to other addresses in the last 4 tax. This doesn’t look like yours. These amounts are usually managed by exchanges... so it might be vice versa. I have the feeling that your “receive” address is wrong. Certainly I can’t help any further, best seems to be to get in touch with your provider.